# Heredoc not preserving blank line

Tags: bash

Here I'm trying to declare a variable with multi-line value in `bash`:

```
$ GET="$(cat <<EOF
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:80
> 
> EOF
> )"
```

That works for sure, however blank line at the end of the doc is lost:

```
$ echo "$GET"
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:80
$ cat <<< "$GET"
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually not the heredoc that trims the trailing newline, but the command substitution. Consider using `read` instead:

```
$ IFS= read -r -d '' var << EOF
>   hello
> world
> 
> EOF
$ printf "%s" "$var"
  hello
world

$
```

Note that `printf` usually doesn't print a trailing newline, so the variable `var` actually have two trailing newlines.

Alternative you can simply use multi line strings:

```
var="  hello
world
"
```

Comment: Why is it important to set `IFS` to `null`?

Comment: @NarūnasK See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read . In your case it could properly be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

command substitution `$( )`  automatically remove trailing newlines when assign to variable.
so you need one more work to use heredoc in your code like this

```
$ GET=$(cat <<EOF
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:80

.    # ends with a period for preserve trailing newlines
EOF
)

$ GET=${GET%.}   # remove the period
```

Answer (score 2):

I was doing something like this today. Creating a file using a heredoc.
The file kept on ending up as one big line of text. The solution was to double quote the variable I was echoing into the file.

```
base_name_no_extension="DEMO"

DEMO_C99_CODE=$(cat << DEMO_C99_CODE_HERE_DOC
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #include "GLEB_SWIN.H"                      //
                                                //
    int                                         //
    main(                                       //
        void                                    //
    ){                                          //
                                                //
        GLEB_SWIN_Demonstration();              //
                                                //
    }                                           //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
DEMO_C99_CODE_HERE_DOC
)

touch $base_name_no_extension.C99
>     $base_name_no_extension.C99
echo "$DEMO_C99_CODE" >> $base_name_no_extension.C99
          ##
        ######
      ##########
    ##############
  ##################
         ####
         ####
         ####
         ####
         ####
         ####
    #########################
    ##                     ##
    ##    DOUBLE QUOTES!   ##
    ##                     ##
    #########################
```